# A basic minimization problem over finite fields

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms

Let $p$ be a prime, and suppose we are given $n$ values mod $p$: $a_1,...,a_n\in Z_p$.  Is there a fast algorithm for finding $\alpha\in Z_p$ which minimizes the value $\max_i (\alpha\cdot a_i$ mod $p$)?  If we think of the $n$ values as a vector $\vec a\in Z_p^n$, I want to know if there is a way to find the point on the line spanned by $\vec a$ which has minimum $\ell_\infty$ norm.

Of course when $p$ is small, one can simply examine all values of $\alpha\in Z_p$, however I am wondering whether there is a polynomial time (in $n$) algorithm even for large values of $p$ (say $p\approx 2^n$).

Comment: This amounts to finding a short vector in the lattice in $\mathbb Z^n$ generated by the $n+1$ vectors $(a_1,\ldots,a_n),(p,0,\ldots,0),(0,p,\ldots,0),\ldots,(0,0,\ldots,p)$. The [LLL algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) might help.